# Powershell WPF StackPanel not updating correctly

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, user-interface

I'm writing an 'idle launching screen' for my Powershell UI launch page, using a WPF XAML form and Powershell [Windows.Markup.XamlReader].

When launching an external script, the launch page goes into an 'idle' mode, which is when the 'idle launching screen' comes in.

An example of the 'idle launching screen' when working correctly:
[image]

Now the issue is: when launching an external WPF UI (including an external WPF Powershell script) for the first time, the 'idle launching screen' works perfectly fine. Yet, when closing that external WPF UI and re-opening a different one (still in the same PSSession), the 'idle launching screen' looks weird. As if the StackPanel it's inside goes all the way to the foreground ignoring any *Opacity* or *ZIndex* settings (example can be found at the imgur link below).

My WPF StackPanel:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="Launching" Visibility="Visible">
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0.077"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="2"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </StackPanel.Background>

        <StackPanel Margin="0,180,0,0" Height="200" Width="200" Background="Transparent">
            <wfi:WindowsFormsHost Margin="50,-30,0,0">
                <winForms:PictureBox x:Name="pictureBoxLoading">
                </winForms:PictureBox>
            </wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
            <Label Content="Applicatie lanceren..." Width="115" Margin="0,-29,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Powershell code behind the form:

```
## Loading the .gif
$pictureBoxLoading.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile("C:\Images\rocket.gif")

## Triggers
$Launching.Visibility = [System.Windows.Visibility]::Visible
$Launching.Visibility = [System.Windows.Visibility]::Hidden
```

Video example of my issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YN7N.jpg

Comment: how do you trigger the overlay and how is the blue overlay implemented

Comment: @T-Me I edited the post. Noticed not all of the code was copy-pasted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `WindowsFormsHost`, because it's a WinForms object and not natively in WPF supported. Get it named (`<wfi:WindowsFormsHost x:Name="Host"...`) and hide it too. Then make it visible after the rest of your loadingscreen:

```
function hide {
    $Launching.Visibility = [System.Windows.Visibility]::Hidden
    $Host.Visibility = [System.Windows.Visibility]::Hidden
}

function show {
    $Launching.Visibility = [System.Windows.Visibility]::Visible
    $Host.Visibility = [System.Windows.Visibility]::Visible    
}
```

Comment: My goodness, thanks for this! Works like a charm (except $host in PoSh is already used, so I named it $Host1).